# Using JSON arrays in SenseNet settings

Tags: json, odata, sensenet

If JSON arrays are used in a SenseNet settings object, they are not accessible via the OData API.

For example, consider the following SenseNet settings object, which comes installed at `Root/System/Settings/Portal.settings` by default:

```
{
    ClientCacheHeaders: [
        { ContentType: "PreviewImage", MaxAge: 1 },
        { Extension: "jpeg", MaxAge: 604800 },
        { Extension: "gif", MaxAge: 604800 },
        { Extension: "jpg", MaxAge: 604800 },
        { Extension: "png", MaxAge: 604800 },
        { Extension: "swf", MaxAge: 604800 },
        { Extension: "css", MaxAge: 600 },
        { Extension: "js", MaxAge: 600 }
    ],
    UploadFileExtensions: {
        "jpg": "Image",
        "jpeg": "Image",
        "gif": "Image",
        "png": "Image",
        "bmp": "Image",
        "svg": "Image",
        "svgz": "Image",
        "tif": "Image",
        "tiff": "Image",
        "xaml": "WorkflowDefinition",
        "DefaultContentType": "File"
    },
    BinaryHandlerClientCacheMaxAge: 600,
    PermittedAppsWithoutOpenPermission: "Details"
}
```

When viewing this object through the OData API, the ClientCacheHeaders field is not included:

```
{
    "d": {
        "UploadFileExtensions.jpg": "Image",
        "UploadFileExtensions.jpeg": "Image",
        "UploadFileExtensions.gif": "Image",
        "UploadFileExtensions.png": "Image",
        "UploadFileExtensions.bmp": "Image",
        "UploadFileExtensions.svg": "Image",
        "UploadFileExtensions.svgz": "Image",
        "UploadFileExtensions.tif": "Image",
        "UploadFileExtensions.tiff": "Image",
        "UploadFileExtensions.xaml": "WorkflowDefinition",
        "UploadFileExtensions.DefaultContentType": "File",
        "BinaryHandlerClientCacheMaxAge": 600,
        "PermittedAppsWithoutOpenPermission": "Details",
    }
}
```

If you search specifically for the ClientCacheHeaders field using the following query:

```
Odata.svc/Root/System/Settings('Portal.settings')?&metadata=no&$select=ClientCacheHeaders
```

the API returns null:

```
{
    "d": {
        "ClientCacheHeaders": null
    }
}
```

I know that JSON arrays are allowed in settings files because the above example is referenced in the [SenseNet wiki page](http://wiki.sensenet.com/Settings#Arrays_.28JSON_only.29) describing settings usage.

Am I performing my OData query incorrectly, or is this some sort of parsing bug in the SenseNet API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an implementation of the custom OData function suggested by Miklos. Once this is done, you have to register the OData call as described [here](http://wiki.sensenet.com/How_to_create_a_custom_OData_action#3._Register_the_action).

```
public static class OData
{
    [ODataFunction]
    public static string GetMySettings(Content content)
    {
        var retstr = "";
        try
        {
            var settingsFile = Settings.GetSettingsByName<Settings>("MySettings", content.Path);
            var node = Node.LoadNode(settingsFile.Path) as Settings;
            var bindata = node.GetBinary("Binary");

            using (var sr = bindata.GetStream())
            using (var tr = new System.IO.StreamReader(sr))
                retstr = tr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            SnLog.WriteException(e);
        }

        return retstr; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a limitation of the current *dynamic json field conversion* behind the odata api. It actually converts these setting json properties to **sensenet fields**, so what you see in the odata response is not the actual settings json, but only the fragments that can be converted to sensenet fields (for the curious: it happens in the *JsonDynamicFieldHelper* class, *BuildDynamicFieldMetadata* method).

And unfortunately there is **no built-in field type** in sensenet for handling json arrays, it is not possible to convert a json array to a field value, this is why the system skips it.

#### Workaround 1

Get the raw settings json in javascript **in two steps**. The following request gives you the binary field's direct url:

```
/odata.svc/Root/System/Settings('Portal.settings')?&metadata=no&$select=Binary
```

...something like this:

```
/binaryhandler.ashx?nodeid=1084&propertyname=Binary&checksum=1344168
```

...and if you load that, you'll get the full raw json, including the array.

> Please note: Settings are not accessible to visitors by
>   default, for a reason: they may contain sensitive information. So if
>   you want to let your users access settings directly (the way you tried
>   or the way described in the first workaround above), you'll have to
>   give **open permission** for the necessary user groups on those setting
>   files. This is not the case with the second workaround.

#### Workaround 2

Create a [custom odata action](http://wiki.sensenet.com/Generic_Sense/Net_OData_action) that returns settings in a format of your choice from the server. This is a better solution, because this way you control which parts of a setting file is actually accessible to the client.